# Create URLs for different data frames

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, python-requests, python-twitter

I have a data frame that I split into different data frames of size 100 (to be able to make Python able to process it).
Therefore, I get different data frames (df1 to df..). For all those data frames, I want to create an URL as shown below.

When I use `type(df)`, it shows me it is a data frame, however, when I use `for j in dfs: print(type(j))`, it is shown it is a string. I need the data frame to make it able to create the URL.

Can you please help me what the loop for creating the urls for all data frames could look like?

Thank you so much for your help!

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pd.json_normalize(tweets_data), orient='columns')


n = 100  #chunk row size
list_df = [df[i:i+n] for i in range(0,df.shape[0],n)]

dfs = {}
for idx,df in enumerate(list_df, 1):
    dfs[f'df{idx}'] = df

type(df1)

for j in dfs:
    print(type(j))

def create_url():
     url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets?{}&{}".format("ids=" + (str(str((df1['id'].tolist()))[1:-1])).replace(" ", ""), tweet_fields)
     return url
```

Comment: Can your print an example of the string that comes out?

Comment: Can you also share the dataframe?

Comment: df 
Out[144]: 
                           created_at  ...  coordinates.coordinates
12400  Wed Aug 04 21:57:59 +0000 2021  ...                      NaN
12401  Wed Aug 04 21:58:07 +0000 2021  ...                      NaN

Comment: It is basically a data frame of all the Twitter data, e.g., creation data, coordinates, text, but I am only interested in the column id

Comment: My final string looks similar to that: 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets?ids=1422935798802960386,1422935813466243072, ...

Comment: if `dfs` is dictionary then `for j in dfs:` gives you only keys - which are string. You need `for j in dfs.values():` or `for key, j in df.items():`

Answer (score 0):

`dfs` is dictionary so `for j in dfs:` gives you only `keys` - which are string.

You need `.values()`

```
for j in dfs.values():
```

or `.items()`

```
for key, j in df.items():
```

or you have to use `dfs[j]`

```
for j in dfs:
    print(type( dfs[j] ))
```

---

**EDIT:**

Frankly, you could do it all in one loop without `list_df`

```
import pandas as pd

#df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pd.json_normalize(tweets_data), orient='columns')
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': range(1000)})

tweet_fields = 'something'

n = 100  #chunk row size

for i in range(0, df.shape[0], n):
    ids = df[i:i+n]['id'].tolist()
    ids_str = ','.join(str(x) for x in ids)
    url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets?ids={}&{}".format(ids_str, tweet_fields)
    print(url)
```

You can also use `groupby` and `index` if index uses numbers 0,1,...

```
for i, group in df.groupby(df.index//100):
    ids = group['id'].tolist()
    ids_str = ','.join(str(x) for x in ids)
    url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets?ids={}&{}".format(ids_str, tweet_fields)
    print(url)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that helps! :) However, now I get the right format but I am not able to create a loop which creates the URL for all id's within one data frame, do you maybe know how I can do it?

Comment: you don't need another loop but you have to run `create_url` inside current loop and you should create function with argument `def create_url(df)`. Better create minimal working code with example data in code - so we could simply copy it and run it.

Comment: frankly, you could do all in single `for`-loop - `for i in range(0,df.shape[0],n)` - without creating `list_df`